# $timeout is not a function error

Tags: angularjs, timeout

Hey guys got a little problem that i cant seem to see the problem for. Im building an angular application and im getting the error stated in the question title. Ive injected the `$timeout` to the controller but im still getting an error with this bit of code can some one tell me where i may be going wrong?

cheers

```
(function() {
'use strict';
angular
    .module('my.module')
    .controller('NewSearchController', NewSearchController);

NewSearchController.$inject = ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$location','UserService',
  'SearchService', '$window', '$controller', '$mdDialog', 'ModalService', '$routeParams', '$timeout'];


/**
 *   @namespace ContactController
 */

function NewSearchController($rootScope, $scope, $location, UserService, SearchService, $window, $controller, $mdDialog, $routeParams, $timeout)
```

**Timeout code:**

```
var timerMax = false;
    $scope.$watch(NewSearchController.searchObject.maxDayRate, function(){
      if(timerMax) {
        $timeout.cancel(timerMax);
      }
      timerMax= $timeout(function() {
        NewSearchController.updateSearchFilters();
      }, 5000);
    });
```

Comment: Please try and post complete code samples. Your error is probably related to how you inject `$timeout` but without seeing everything I'm just guessing.

Comment: edited my question to show how it is injected.

Comment: added my answer explaining where you got the injection wrong.

Comment: As always for this kind of bugs: use [ng-annotate](https://github.com/olov/ng-annotate).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in your injection: 'ModalService' listed as injectable but not one of the parameters so angular will inject 'ModalService' and the values you get for parameters later in the list are all wrong.

If you use something like gulp to build your app then use gulp-ng-annotate to build the injection list automatically. That way it won't go wrong and you never have to worry about it.

Comment: cheers this may be a case of me looking at the code for to long. ill check this out and acceot the answer if it fixes it thanks for the fresh pair of eyes :P

Comment: Seems to work will accept your answer when the question timer runs out (who knew stackoverflow made you wait to acceot answers)

Answer (score 0):

```
    '$mdDialog', 'ModalService', '$routeParams', '$timeout']


$mdDialog, $routeParams, $timeout
```

**these two dnt match Change it to**

```
$mdDialog,ModalService, $routeParams, $timeout
```

Answer (score 0):

you have injected $timeout at position 11th position in controller but in function it is at 10th position as u have missed ModalService in function.So the error is just because of this . You need to inject and add the dependcies at same position otherwise it wont work.